# How to Authenticate user with Login and Password?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Looking at this solution for Angular 2:

```
state: string = '';
error: any;

constructor(public af: AngularFire,private router: Router) {
this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => { 
  if(auth) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
  }
});
}


 onSubmit(formData) {
if(formData.valid) {
  console.log(formData.value);
  this.af.auth.login({
    email: formData.value.email,
    password: formData.value.password
  },
  {
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password,
  }).then(
    (success) => {
    console.log(success);
    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.error = err;
  })
}
}
```

I have been trying to get the same functionality to work in Angular 4, but get

> Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Here is some sample code (not working):

```
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts } from "angularfire2/interfaces";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, 
FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 
'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 
'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent {
  state: string = '';
   error: any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: 
   AngularFireDatabase,private router: Router) {
   this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => { 
  if(auth) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
    }
   });
 }


onSubmit(formData) {
if(formData.valid) {
  console.log(formData.value);
  this.afAuth.authState.login({
    email: formData.value.email,
    password: formData.value.password
  },
  {
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password,
  }).then(
    (success) => {
    console.log(success);
    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.error = err;
    })
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using different libraries in the two examples; have you tried reading the docs for the one you're using to see how you're supposed to be doing it?

Comment: i readed but i didnt understand im new in angular :/

Comment: Then I'd recommend reading more docs and tutorials - as it stands you're treating `authState` as an observable in one place, by `.subscribe`-ing to it, and in another place treating it like it has a `.login` method that it apparently does not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right. You should look into how services and observables work. Especially if you're going to be making network requests. Take a look at this article for an example using Angular's `http` module and observables. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Answer (score 1):

It seems like half of your code is AF2 2.0 and the other half 4.0, [see our migration guide on the API changes that we made](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md).

Namely, AngularFire2 no longer provides wrappers for the Firebase Javascript SDK. [You need to use that SDK to login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth):

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
...
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
...
this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
```

If you're curious about why we decided to not wrap the JS SDK, [you can check out the proposal in the AngularFire2 Github Issues](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854).